# Convert Python string to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have a JavaScript script which receives information from a Python server. The Python server outputs a list, which is converted to a string prior to being sent to the JavaScript script.

I'd like to be able to convert the received string into a form that can be indexed with JavaScript. Here's an example output string from the Python server:

```
var Message = [['Word1A', 'Word1B'], ['Word2A', 'Word2B'], ['Word3A', 'Word3B']];
```

Given the above example, I'd like to be able to query the received string as as an indexed array:

```
var x;
for (x in Message) {
    alert(x[0]};
```

The above example should return:

```
Word1A
Word2A
Word3A
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Which way you use for data transport? If it is the HTTP protocol and AJAX requests you can add content/type header like it is done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type. And on the client side it will be parsed automatically to JavaScript list or you can insert string into template as JS list.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm struggling with how to convert the string into an indexed array.

Comment: @ErDmKo I'm using websockets, and am only able to emit strings (no lists/arrays).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) Python module

```
reply = json.dumps(Message)
```

to convert the array in a JSON formatted string.

Then on the client side you decode the JSON string with

```
message = JSON.parse(msg);
```

and you will get an array of 2-elements arrays

Comment: I really like this approach, but I'm unable to make it work. Python produces a nested list (as per original post); do I need to do anything to it before using the json.dumps() method?

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
var Message = [['Word1A', 'Word1B'], ['Word2A', 'Word2B'], ['Word3A', 'Word3B']];
var x;
for (x in Message) {
    alert(Message[x][0]);
}
```

Editing my answer as per you comments below which says the input would be 
`"['Word1A', 'Word1B'], ['Word2A', 'Word2B'], ['Word3A', 'Word3B']"`

Solution being,

```
var Message = "['Word1A', 'Word1B'], ['Word2A', 'Word2B'], ['Word3A', 'Word3B']";
var array = Message.replace(/,|[|]/g, "").split(" ");
for(var x = 0; x < array.length -1; x=x+2){
 alert(array[x].replace("[","").replace("]",""));
}
```

I must add, this solution will work but I'm not that fluent with regex, so more optimal solution could be achieved.
Hope it helps!

Comment: As Message is a string (not an array), this prints each individual letter to the alert console. This would be correct if Message had been converted into a JavaScript array prior to printing.

Comment: so you mean the input is, `"['Word1A', 'Word1B'], ['Word2A', 'Word2B'], ['Word3A', 'Word3B']"`??

Comment: Yes that's correct. The input is a list, converted to a string, from Python.

Comment: Yes it did, to an extent. I've decided to change my approach for the time being though. Thanks again for all your help!